# Running a process in the background

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 questions about starting the processes in the background:

1. Why does starting a process in the background like so:

   `./my_program &`

   (`my_program` have exe permission set of course) doesn't make the
   bash to print the command prompt like any other commands? It just
   left a empty new line with blinking cursor.
2. When i run a next new processes in the background bash displays sth.
   like that:

   `./my_program & 
   [30] 1439 
   [27] Done ./my_program 
   [28] Done ./my_program 
   [29] Done ./my_program`

   does this mean that starting
   another extra processes in the background makes the system to
   display an info about the previews processes (`[27], [28], [29]`
   lines) as long as the currently started) (`[30]` line)?

Comment: What happens if you just press `<return>` again? do you get a prompt?

Answer (score 0):

1. This shouldn't happen. When you run a command in the background bash usually just prints the job number and pid (see below) and then drops back to a command prompt.

   The only reason I know of that leads bash to leave you with a new line in this situation is if your command doesn't actually exist, as it will somehow give the error message for that after printing PS1:

   ```
   $ nonexistant_command &
   [1] 13856
   $
   nonexistant_command: command not found
   <empty line with blinking cursor here>
   ```

   Whatever the cause may be, pressing enter while on this empty line should print a new line with your usual prompt (and, possibly, the message that the job you just spawned finished; see below).
2. The additional output you see is bash telling you about current background jobs:

   First, it tells you the current job number of any newly created background process together with its pid, like so:

   ```
   $ some_command &
   [1] 1234
   ```

   This means that the command `some_command` is now being run with the pid 1234 as job 1.

   Once a background job finishes, bash will notify you of this the next time it prints a command prompt (whether it be because you spawned another background process, ran a command in the foreground or simply pressed enter with an empty command line) by printing a message like this:

   ```
   [1]  Done                    some_command
   ```

   This means that the job with the number 1 which ran `some_command` has now finished.

   To find out what background jobs bash is currently tracking, you can use the `jobs` builtin like so:

   ```
   $ jobs
   [1]  Running                 some_command &
   [2]  Running                 some_other_command &
   ```

   To bring a job to the foreground, you can use `fg`:

   ```
   $ fg 2
   some_other_command
   ```

   For more info on this, try `help jobs`